# 'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, cmd, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert group of images `.png` to video `.webm`:

```
ffmpeg -i %03d.png output.webm
```

Getting error:

```
'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Using Windows 10.

Comment: You need to install `ffmpeg` using this installation tutorial : https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/how-to-install-ffmpeg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 solutions:

- Put `ffmpeg.exe` into the folder that has your PNG images.
- Or, in `cmd` provide the full path to `ffmpeg.exe`. Example:

  ```
   "C:\Users\Mark\Downloads\ffmpeg-20210913-28f7a91-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i %03d.png output.webm
  ```
- Or, [add the folder with `ffmpeg.exe` into your system `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows).

Comment: if ffmpeg.exe is in your current path, then you can call it with .\ffmpeg